# Cakephp 3 mySQL table name

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am tiny to word with CakePHP its new for me.
I have a script that saves to the database
`this->Users->save($data)`.
In the database I have a table named 'users' (First letter is not capital letter).

Where do I set that users = Users.
Form what I read it should be in user Modal But I did not fined it there
Thanks

Comment: You should have a UsersTable class under `src/Model/Table`. That would be the class that `$this->Users` will reference in, for example, your UsersController. The initialization of that object is where the name of the actual database table is set.

Comment: $this->Users refers to the model's object (not a table). inside the src/Model/Table/UsersTable : initialization() method, db-table is linked eg: $this->setTable('users'); . if no Model is defined, then it will proceed with default Model object. You can use <a href="https://dev.to/northgoingzax/cakephp-3-bake-by-example-40pp" target="_blank">bake</a> command to build model quickly, then customize as per your need.